# Is this a bounded linear map?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I tried very hard to (dis)prove it, but now I give up.

Define a map which maps $x\in L_2[0,1]$ to the function

$$(Tx)(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int_0^t \frac{x(s)}{\sqrt{s}} \,d s.$$

I don't even know if it maps to $L_2[0,1]$. I tried all the obvious candidates for counter-examples and the outcomes live in $L_2$. Note that the obvious estimates of $\|Tx\|^2$ using e.g. the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality do not lead to anything conclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon > 0$, and $x(s):= s^{\varepsilon-1/2}$. Then $\left\| x\right\|_{2}^{2} =\frac{1}{2\varepsilon}$, and $\left\| T[x]\right\|_{2}^{2} = \frac{1}{2\varepsilon^3}$. So
\begin{align}
\left\|T[x]\right\|_{2} = \frac{1}{\varepsilon} \left\|x\right\|_{2},
\end{align}
i.e., $\left\|T\right\|_{2} \ge \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$, for every $\varepsilon > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The post by Nick Thompson answer you question. Let me just add that the point here is not that $Tx$ is not in $L^2$. As a matter of fact, the operator maps $L^2$ to itself. The point is that the *norm* of the operator is not bounded. So when you say "I tried all the obvious candidates for counter-examples and the outcomes live in $L^2$", you are not addressing your original question.

Comment: Why $Tx$ is not in $L^2$?

Comment: You can show that using a meta argument, yet I don't have any concrete counter-example.

Comment: I misunderstood your words: in your question it sounded to me like you were trying to find $x$ such that $Tx$ is not in $L^2$. What I meant in my answer was that the point is not whether or not $Tx$ is in $L^2$ for any choice of $x$ (and, in fact, it is), but rather that you cannot bound the norm of $Tx$ uniformly. Nick's answer show's one example of a family of functions $x_\varepsilon$ such that $||Tx_\varepsilon||/||x_\varepsilon||$ is not uniformly bounded with respect to the parameter $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I don't believe that $Tx$ is always in $L_2$. Otherwise, you would have constructed an unbounded linear operator on a Hilbert space without using the axiom of choice.

Comment: You can build many unbounded linear operators on Hilbert spaces. What does that have to do with the Axiom of Choice?

Comment: Please give an example of an unbounded operator $\ell_2\to \ell_2$ (which is defined on the whole of $\ell_2$) without using AC.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I need to appeal to some variant of the AC in order to build it on the whole space, cause I can do it only on a dense subspace but then I need to extend it to the whole space. I deserve a -1 for this...

Ok, now that we clarified this, I take back the fact that $Tx$ is always in $L^2$. However, as Nick showed, you can restrict $T$ to a subspace where you show that it is unbounded. That should be enough for you.